# How to use a module from the interactive Ruby shell?

Tags: ruby

Ruby newbie here. I'm trying to use the Easyjour module ( http://easyjour.rubyforge.org/ ) from irb. After a `gem install easyjour` this is what I get:

```
irb(main):002:0> service = Easyjour.serve("files", 'http', 3000)
NameError: uninitialized constant Easyjour
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to import the module first somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to first load the `easyjour` library, before you can use any code from it:

```
require 'easyjour'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Jorg's approach is to load the module at the command line when starting `irb`:

```
irb -r easyjour
```